# Batch file won't start VBS Printer Script

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

Guys I've created a basic logon script mapping network drives and would like that batch file to call the printer .vbs script.  This is the command after my last "net use" command in the batch file, to launch the .vbs file in the same directory.

```
start \\<Server>\c$\<directory>\Printers.vbs
```

What is the correct command to launch the .vbs file?

Comment: What is wrong with *your* command?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `cscript`.

```
cscript Printers.vbs
```

Comment: Thanks, @Bali! I was able to get it going with the appropriate syntax as follows: Option Explicit

strUNCPrinter1 = "\\appsrv01\Grimlock"
strUNCPrinter2 = "\\appsrv01\Iceman"
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\appsrv01\grimlock"
objNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\appsrv01\Iceman"

Dim objNetwork, strLocal, strUNCPrinter1, strUNCPrinter2

WScript.Quit